# Can 'os' module in python be run without an OS?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python project which uses the 'os' module. My plan is to convert it to C using Cython, then a C compiler to get it into assembly, and NASM to convert it to binary. I read that the os module is OS dependent, so will

```
os.path.isdir(), os.path.isfile and os.listdir
```

functions work after my lengthy conversion? Does it have anything to do with file systems?

Comment: They'll work, but note that you'd still need the Python interpreter and the `os.path` module. You can embed them in your executable (Cython has an option for that), nonetheless you'd still run a few lines of pure-Python code when calling `os.path.isdir()`

Comment: If you don't have an OS, you don't have a file system. What would you expect these functions to do in such as scenario?  If you do have a file system, then you have *some sort of* platform for using it already. (I'm guessing you use "OS" to mean something else, really.)

Answer (score 0):

When it is said that `os` is OS-dependent, it means that it is different depending on the operating system.  For instance, `os.sep` on Linux would be "/", but on Windows would be "\".  It should still work on any operating system, just slightly differently.  If you actually mean that there *is* no operating system, I wouldn't expect them to work, but I don't think there would be any use for them.

Comment: I am planning to use the 'os.path.isdir', 'os.path.isfile', 'os.listdir' for just browsing through files in a folder and accessing them. So i would need use for them. In case I wasn't so clear, I want to be able to run my .py script completely standalone, no os underneath.

Comment: @UditDey You can't have a file system without an operating system.